# Populate Field in Table to Display Dateadd Results

Tags: populate, dateadd

I asked this question before but I still have not received a response, so I'll ask again hoping that someone has an answer:

Dave, a Stackoverflow member was kind enough to answer my question initial question in how to get my "dateadd" field to display on my report; however, I am still not getting the exact results of what I need. While the field with the dateadd formula displays ouput on the report, it does NOT generated output in the Estimated Date for Completion field of the table based on date info entered in the Test Date field. Is this doable?

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I had a similar issue and this is what I did....

**ACTION DESIRED:** Have one date field trigger (calculate) future or past date values in other date fields in a form and (Most importantly)have those values save in the master database table and queries.

**TRIGGER FIELD:**

```
Re Insp Date
```

**AFFECTED CALCULATED FIELDS:**

```
Re Insp Date 90 Day (To be set to -90 from "Re Insp Date")
Re Insp Date 60 Day (To be set to -60 from "Re Insp Date")
Re Insp Date 30 Day (To be set to -30 from "Re Insp Date")
```

**SOLUTION**:

1. Opened up the properties of what is to be the "trigger" date field
2. Went to 'All' tab
3. Opened up a 'Code Builder' Event Procedure in the "After Update"
   property
4. Entered the following VBA code

   ```
   Private Sub Re_Insp_Date_AfterUpdate()
   Re_Insp_Date_90_Day = Re_Insp_Date - 90
   Re_Insp_Date_60_Day = Re_Insp_Date - 60
   Re_Insp_Date_30_Day = Re_Insp_Date - 30

   End Sub
   ```

**NOTE**: If there are spaces in the name fields, an underscore has to replace the spaces. As shown in the VBA code above, `Re Insp Date` field name must be coded as `Re_Insp_Date`. (This is why many suggest you use no spacing in when naming database fields, tables, queries, forms, objects, etc)

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Anyway, there it is.